# Sidebar with Google Map showing

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having problems getting a Google Map to show up correctly with Bootstrap, here is what I have going so far - [see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yek4p260suOTCZJ7P0jI?p=preview)

`see above`

So on a callback after the Google Maps API loads, I am then initializing the map, but it just wont fill up the available space. I can see from inspecting the elements in chrome debugging tools that the map has loaded in and the maps generated markup appears, but its just the sizing that seems to have gone wrong.

No doubt I have done something wrong, please advise, thanks!

**EDIT**

Ok I have got further now, map showing up just fine, but I am struggling using the grid system to lay out the page so I have space to the left of the map where other content will appear (eventually a sidebar that will show\hide based on screen). But this new [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yek4p260suOTCZJ7P0jI) wont show it, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid is working fine.

You used col-lg which is for large monitors, so u'll see the grid work only on that point.

Specify the other devices too, or you can only use the smallest device that you need.

Example: col-sm-4 and col-sm-8

Comment: Ah yes I see now, makes perfect sense and displays as I would expect. Cheers @Ardian